# OpenMP Parallelizing code-block inside a for loop?

Tags: c++, openmp

Greetings all,

I want to run the code block inside the loop ,in seperate OpenMP thread.
Have I defined correct OpenMP directives in the following code snippet:

```
#ifdef OPENMP_ENABLE
        #pragma omp parallel for
    #endif

for(int i=0;i<numOfSlices;i++){                  // Entire block inside this loop should be fun in new OpenMP thread

        int id =0;

        #ifdef OPENMP_ENABLE
               id=omp_get_thread_num();
              qDebug("------- OPENMP thread number  %d",id);
        #endif
            qDebug("      - Image Slice %d",i);

        int width=0,height=0;
        //Image Buffer
        unsigned char *buff=planeViewer->getImageBuggerOfSlice(i,height,width);

        //Trunk
        RzTrunk *rztrnk=planeViewer->getTrunkOfSlice(i);

        //If Empty trunk,add frame @TODO Hard coded
        if(rztrnk->getCurveCount()==0){
           RzCurve *crv=rztrnk->createFrameCurve(10,10,width-10,height-10);
           rztrnk->addCurve(crv);
        }

       //Covert Rinzo Trunk to Centy Trunk!
       //TODO Make sure to deallocate memory
       QImage *qimg=new QImage(buff,width,height,QImage::Format_RGB32);
       trnk_t *trnkt = convertRzTrunkToCntyTrunk(rztrnk, qimg->width(),qimg->height());


       //Convert QImage to Cnty Image format
       image_t *imgt=convertQImageToImaget(qimg);

       //This extract parts , first should detect outer border
       if(etype==EXTRACT_DEFL_INOUT){
            cnty_extract_contour(EXTRACT_DEFL_OUT, trnkt, imgt, NULL, NULL,settings2, NULL);
            trnk_make_crvs_nodes_active(trnkt);
       }

       cnty_extract_contour(etype, trnkt, imgt, NULL, NULL,settings, NULL);
       convertCntyTrunkToRzTrunk(trnkt, rztrnk);

       trnk_destruct(trnkt);
       destroyImaget(imgt);
       delete qimg;
       delete buff;    
} //end of for loop
```

Comment: Looks ok - if your intention was to slice the for loop and have it processed by different openmp work threads, where is the problem? What is the result of the loop ... maybe writing it would require "#pragma omp citical"

Comment: the line "RzTrunk *rztrnk=planeViewer->getTrunkOfSlice(i);" actually get an instance from a linked list and all the processing is done on this *rztrnk variable.Result is just the modified entries in the linked-list.

Comment: So the data of different i's do not interfere? Then the above code should work.

Comment: this *rztrnk contains a vector based contour data which is processed using the bitmap data of *qimg.The result is different for same image when using OpenMP.But when using sequential its identical.

Comment: Ok, I can only guess. But there might be something fishy going on in the getImageBuggerOfSlice or getTrunkOfSlice routine. You can try to "protect" them with a "critical pragma" it will cost some speedup but might tell you more about the origin of the problem.

Comment: `QImage *qimg=new QImage(` is performance hit.  why not just `QImage qimg(`?

Comment: I'd try to take care about correctness first.

Comment: thanks FFbox , I had a discussion with the coworker who implemented "cnty_extract_contour()" function.Seems it is not thread safe! Thats the whole reason for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  found the issue.the reason was that the "cnty_extract_contour()" method is not thread-safe.